Isekai manga where the main character wakes up as a demon lord or something
I'm looking for an isekai manga where the main character wakes up as a demon lord or something similar in status. They have just conquered a city or a fort, and they need to decide what to do with the people of the said city. The main character decides to spare them or make use of them, and his subordinates question his decision. There is this sly elf subordinate of his that tries to pull some shit, but it does not work out.
This may be somewhat inaccurate, as I read this manga back in 2018 or 2019 and want to see how it is going.
It is not The Strongest Magician in Demon King Army.

Quick question, Is the MC shocked when he wake up as a demon lord or not. And the panel, is MC question himself is this a game or not and his subordinate told him the situation? Or is the subordinate told they need him as an alternative? Base on your content this is kinda cliche. Trope is just MC as Demon King -> OP -> Betray his species by shakehand with human -> Peace for the world
